# Listening with 2 sockets on server

Tags: c, linux, sockets, bind

I've created a server that listens on 1 socket that works fine, and now I need to add another socket.

I've read some questions/answers here about how to create it, but so far without any success.

I'm running both clients and server on my local laptop, and as I'm trying to bind the second socket, I'm getting the follow error: `bind: Address already in use` while running the server, in the terminal.

Can anyone give me maybe a little hint about what I'm doing wrong and how can I create 2 sockets to listen on the same address?

```
  int s, s2, len, b, b2, blen;
  struct sockaddr_un local, remote, blocal;
  socklen_t t, bt;
  if ((b = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
     perror("socket");
      exit(1);
    }
  if ((s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("socket");
    exit(1);
  }

  blocal.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
  strcpy(blocal.sun_path,SOCK_PATH);
  unlink(blocal.sun_path);
  local.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
  strcpy(local.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);
  unlink(local.sun_path);

  len = strlen(local.sun_path) + sizeof(local.sun_family);
  blen = strlen(blocal.sun_path) + sizeof(blocal.sun_family);
  if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr * ) & local, len) == -1) {
    perror("bind");
    exit(1);
  }

 if (bind(b, (struct sockaddr * ) & blocal, blen) == -1) {
    perror("bind");
    exit(1);
  }
```

I've cut the rest of the code where it gets to listen etc since that's where I get the error.

Comment: `how can I create 2 sockets to listen on the same address?` No, you cannot.

Comment: @joop basically one of the main objective of this is `We​ ​ will​ ​ have​ ​ TWO​ ​ listening​ ​ sockets.​ ​ One​ ​ for​ ​ network​ ​ elements​ ​ and
one​ ​ for​ ​ management​ ​ queries`, meaning some clients will connect, and also a management console, through a different socket... Any suggestions?
The quotation btw is what my lecturer gave us..

Comment: {protocol, address, portnumber} should unique. so, in your case, at least the portnumber should differ. The unix-domain sockets *seem* to obfuscate this requirement, but in fact it is still valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two sockets cannot listen on same port number, you need to create two sockets binding to different ports and then have a load balancer in front of them to share the load across.

Or, if you want to create one socket but the requests should be handled by multiple threads or processes then you can utilize shared memory concept (usually in C or C++). So when request comes in then the server socket process  can copy the request content to shared memory and then the child processes or threads can pick the request from it and then process further.

This model is being used by apache HTTP server.

Comment: If I'll change the code, in a way that each socket will listen through a different port, it should work?

Comment: Yes it should. or at least it wont give error which is in question.

Comment: For AF_UNIX you need different path names as you don't have ports.